# Paypal Rest services - Response: Internal Service Error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is my code. I am not using Maven or curl.

```
String encoding = Base64.encodeBase64String((clientId + ":" + clientSecret).getBytes());
encoding = encoding.replaceAll("\n", "");

URL url1 = new URL("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "client_credentials");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());

if (conn.getResponseCode() == 500) {
InputStream error = conn.getErrorStream();
BufferedReader er = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(error));
String erLine;
while ((erLine = er.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(erLine);
}
}

InputStream content = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
}
conn.disconnect();
```

OUTPUT:

500
{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"023ff49775e72"}

PROBLEM:

Well, when I do this call using curl, it gives me an appropriate response. Are the services not equipped to do communication is this way ?

Comment: So, in what language is your chunk of code? BTW, it's nice that the `information_link` it's dead...

Comment: I am coding in Java. They have a sdk which allows me do all of this. But I was trying to avoid Maven installation in my system.

Comment: You can still use the SDK without using maven. You can download the JAR plus sample app as a zip here http://paypal.github.io/#payments-tab-java

Comment: Yea @Prasanna_Paypal, I got it working with the SDK. Finally. Thanks. At first, I was not able to build my application probably because of some conflicting jars.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print your `Authorization` header and inspect whether it's correctly populated? We are currently returning a HTTP500 if your Authorization header is empty (which we'll change to return a more appropriate error obviously).

Comment: Well I tried to access the "Authorization" header just after setting it. conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding); . And i access it using - System.out.println("Authorization header: " + conn.getRequestProperty("Authorization")); And I get the value NULL. That can't be possible.

Comment: Or print 'encoding'. What does that give you?